# SCCM 2007 collection Query, not approved machines with particular site code

Tags: collections, sccm, system-center, sccm-2007

I am trying to have a sccm 2007 collection query which can populate "not approved" and assigned to site code "AA1" - machines. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find things like this by googling 'SCCM Collection Query' and then describe what you're looking for.

Here's how to do your particular task:

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,
SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,
SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,
SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_CM_RES_COLL_SMS00001 on
SMS_CM_RES_COLL_SMS00001.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
where SMS_CM_RES_COLL_SMS00001.IsApproved= ‘0‘ and SMS_R_System.SMSInstalledSites = "XYZ"
```

The juciest bits are in the last two lines, while the remainder in the beginning is kind of just SCCM WQL Cruft:

```
where SMS_CM_RES_COLL_SMS00001.IsApproved= ‘0‘ and SMS_R_System.SMSInstalledSites = "XYZ"
```

Comment: Thank you for the query, but this did not work..shows and error and no output.

Comment: Please update your question with a screen shot and description of what is happening when you run this query. If you out yourself in my shoes,it Is impossible to help if you simply say "this causes an error".